# Python Pulling from Datasheets

Tags: python

I am trying to create code to pull from a data sheet. My goal is to find the longest song, songs by year, and songs by an artist. Problem is, that when I run what I currently have I get a value returned of 0. Obviously this is not correct. What ways can I do to solve this? I have linked the data sheet here. Click [here](https://www.cs.montana.edu/paxton/classes/csci127/programs/program3/music.csv)!

def longest_song():
        pass
        def songs_by_year(year):
        total=0
        with open('music.csv', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                time = line.split(",")
                song = time[34]
                if song == year:
                    total = total + 1
        return total
        def all_songs_by_artist(artist):
        total = int(0)

```
    data = open("music.csv", "r")
    for line in data:
        name = line.split(",")
        song = name[2]
        if song == artist:
            total = total + 1
        return total
    # --------------------------------------

    def menu():
    print()
    print("1. Identify longest song.")
    print("2. Identify number of songs in a given year.")
    print("3. Identify all songs by a given artist.")
    print("4. You choose something that is interesting and non-trivial.")
    print("5. Quit.")

    # --------------------------------------

    def main():
    choice = 0
    while (choice != 5):
        menu()
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        if (choice == 1):
            longest_song()
        elif (choice == 2):
            year = int(input("Enter desired year: "))
            number = songs_by_year(year)
    ##            print("The number of songs from", "{:,d}".format(number))
            print(number)

        elif (choice == 3):
            artist = input("Enter name of artist: ").lower()
            all_songs_by_artist(artist)
            number = all_songs_by_artist(artist)
            print("There are", "{:,d}".format(number))
        elif (choice == 4):
            pass
        elif (choice != 5):
            print("That is not a valid option.  Please try again.")

    # --------------------------------------

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting input artist to lowercase but Not changing the artist from the file to lower case, thus no matches.
You are converting the Year to an `int` but not doing so to the year from the file.
It is difficult to tell if there are other issues, as your code sample is not indented properly.
I'm guessing but I suppose that it should look something like this.

```
def longest_song(): pass

def songs_by_year(year):
    total=0
    with open('music.csv', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            time = line.split(",")
            song = time[34]
            try:
                if int(song) == year:
                    total = total + 1
            except:
                pass
        return total

def all_songs_by_artist(artist):
    total = int(0)
    with open("music.csv", "r") as data:
        for line in data:
            name = line.split(",")
            song = name[2].lower()
            if song == artist:
                total = total + 1
    return total
# --------------------------------------

def menu():
    print()
    print("1. Identify longest song.")
    print("2. Identify number of songs in a given year.")
    print("3. Identify all songs by a given artist.")
    print("4. You choose something that is interesting and non-trivial.")
    print("5. Quit.")

    # --------------------------------------

def main():
    choice = 0
    while (choice != 5):
        menu()
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        if (choice == 1):
            longest_song()
        elif (choice == 2):
            year = int(input("Enter desired year: "))
            number = songs_by_year(year)
    ##            print("The number of songs from", "{:,d}".format(number))
            print(number)

        elif (choice == 3):
            artist = input("Enter name of artist: ").lower()
            all_songs_by_artist(artist)
            number = all_songs_by_artist(artist)
            print("There are", "{:,d}".format(number))
        elif (choice == 4):
            pass
        elif (choice != 5):
            print("That is not a valid option.  Please try again.")

# --------------------------------------

main()
```